# How to override CSS in joomla template

Tags: css, joomla, overriding

In my Joomla template I would like to override some styles, so I've created my own css and added styles, also media queries.
Most of all works only if I use the !important keyword and something does not work at all. For example:

```
<div id="content_right" class="span3">
```

In this div I have class and id. I cannot modify the class, because it affects other divs into the template, so I would like to add some style by id. I've added it but it does not work. I've inspected with Firebug and css is correctly loaded. what could be the problem?

Comment: can you give much more information. i.e. are you modifying any joomla plugin?

Comment: no, I have not modified any plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is called [CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Yes, the `!important` rule will override all other styles, but shouldn't be used for this reason.

First, you'll need to call your stylesheet *after* the Joomla stylesheet.

Then, you'll need to use the same specificity (or better) in your stylesheet, as is used in the Joomla stylesheet.

To clarify, consider this sample code:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="subcontent"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Combined with this CSS:

```
#content #subcontent {
    background: yellow;
}
#subcontent {
    background: red;
}
```

```css
#content #subcontent {
  background: yellow;
}
#subcontent {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="subcontent">...</div>
</div>
```

The first selector is clearly more specific than the second one. Therefor, will the background be yellow, and not red.

You are facing the same problem. The first selector is the Joomla stylesheet. So you need to specify the second selector the same (or better) in order to override it:

```
#content #subcontent {
  background: yellow;
}
#content #subcontent {
  background: red;
}
```

```css
#content #subcontent {
  background: yellow;
}
#content #subcontent {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="subcontent">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is really clearful, but I have another question: span3 is a class that affects  more than one element into the page, but I would like to change it only if contains some other class, for example inside a div with class=span3 I have a div with class=innerdiv...how could I change only that external div with span3 class and not all the divs with class=span3?

Comment: That depends on the structure. Can you make a JSFiddle with an example?

Comment: I've solved on my own...the div has class and id so I use id and specificity to change correctly the css