# Overwrite Bootstrap style for a single page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried overwriting the "margin-bottom: 20px" in .nav by changing the value into "margin-bottom: 0" but it does work. It is only used once for a specific webpage.

I don't know what to do?

I still wanto to keep the original value "margin-bottom: 20px" because it is used in other webpages.

```
<style>

.nav{
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: You want a page specific CSS?

Comment: Show the CSS you wrote

Comment: Try adding `!important` to the right of `margin-bottom: 20px`.

Comment: Does Bootstrap css is above your css file?

Comment: Manoj Kumar - yes, one page only.

Comment: You write `nav` (as an element) in your style. The console shows `.nav` (as a class). Might do the trick

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's currently not clear what the problem is.

Comment: LinkinTED - already tried but it failed.

Comment: Add your HTML. Probably has to do with CSS Specificity. Same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574330/how-to-override-css-in-joomla-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inline style which has higher priority and will work since you are using only for a single page.

```
<div class="nav" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you are:

**Firstly**

Matching styles, so

```
<style>

   nav  {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

</style>
```

needs to be

```
<style>

   .nav   { /* note the period/full-stop  */
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

</style>
```

**Secondly**

The `<style>` declaration needs to come **after** the Bootstrap CSS is loaded in the `<head>` of your **specific** page so it overrides the previous CSS statement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to the bootstrap.min.css file before or after your own custom stylesheet / internal page styling?

Also, bootstrap.min.css is targeting the CLASS of nav (`.nav`). You're targeting the HTML5 element `nav`.

EDIT: I notice you changed the `nav` to `.nav` in your OP.